# IP access from WAN on specific UDP Port

Tags: networking

I have developed a client/server application that works great on the LAN and now I want to try to put the client on a remote site and try to get it communicating with a server.  How do I go about doing this?  Is it just provide the ip of the outside world.

I think I have to do some port forwarding stuff on the router to say that if data arrives on this port then go to this computer.  But my question is when a application like Skype is turned on how can we connect to the other persons video stream without having to do any port forwarding?

Any help would be greatly appreicated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to ensure that your ISP gives you a public IP address. Make sure your IP is not in following IP ranges:

- 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255
- 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255
- 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255

If your IP is in one of those ranges - you're in trouble. You could try to contact your ISP for more information (some has public IP as free option, some require you to pay to get one and some don't give public IPs at all).

If you have a public IP address - you need to configure port forwarding on the router. This procedure could be slightly different for different routers, but it boils down to having to define external port that you want to forward, local port (port you want to forward, usually both port numbers are same, unless you want to redirect the external port to different local port), protocol (in your case - UDP) and IP of machine in the LAN to which you want to allow access from WAN.

After that, your machine should be accessible from WAN.

As for your question about the applications like the Skype - there are several ways to avoid port forwarding. First - Skype uses servers, which are accessible from the internet. You don't need to forward ports to access servers on the internet, but server owner might need to do that. Second - Skype uses Peer-to-Peer system. Machines that are not behind NAT (or have port forwarding set up) could act as a kind of server and people who have no port forwarding set up could use their machines to accept connections and sent the data and video streams through them. Because of that, even when idling, Skype could still cause added network load, because it's acting as a part of P2P network.